# How can I make ANSI color codes inside the prompt show up in shell-mode?

Tags: shell-mode

I have `shell-mode` set up to work with ANSI colors. In older versions of Emacs, this extended to the prompt but now it doesn't and the prompt remains uncolored.

`PS1` is set with ANSI color codes which work when it's printed out but don't work in the actual prompt itself:

[image: PS1 set with color.]

I tried following the advice from [an old StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819034/colors-in-emacs-shell-prompt) answer and setting the `comint-highlight-prompt` face to not inherit:

```
(set-face-attribute 'comint-highlight-prompt nil
                    :inherit nil)
```

This made the prompt the same color as normal text, still ignoring ANSI codes:

[image]

It seems like versions of [comint.el](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/emacs/emacs-51/emacs/lisp/comint.el) had a custom-set variable `comint-highlight-prompt` which could be set to `nil`, but the variable doesn't seem to exist on my version of Emacs. (Actually, I'm not sure exactly where that file came from, but I found it on a Google search :).)

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more searching, I found that this is a [known bug](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20084) (bug#20084). It looks like a fix has been pushed to master and should be available in Emacs 25:

> I've now pushed my patch (which, I hope, is a proper fix) to master.
>
> …
>
> This change is only in the master branch
> and has not been back-ported to emacs-24.  So, presumably, 25.1 will be
> the first release where this works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick:

> ## init.el file
>
> ```
> (set-face-attribute 'comint-highlight-prompt nil
>                     :inherit nil)
> ```

and the trick:

> ## init_bash.sh file
>
> ```
> PS1="\[\e[00;32m\]\u\[\e[00m\]@\[\e[00;36m\]\h\[\e[00m\]:\[\e[00;34m\]\w\[\e[00m\]\n\$(printf \"[\[\e[01;31m\]%.*s\[\e[00m\]]\" \$? \$?) \$ "
> ```

The trick is the newline. Emacs only erase last line colors.